# Connecting to rev api net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, file-permissions, dotnet-httpclient

I am having an issue posting to an API. The text items in the Httpclient request is sent. The issue I have is when I send the link to the API (requestBody.media_url). This link must be a public Url. I use  have used ngrok to expose The folder as a public folder (in wwwroot). The external API then can not download the file from the folder.
The external api is Rev.Ai

```
public async Task<ResponseBody> SendAudio()
        {
            RequestBody requestBody = new RequestBody();
            //requestBody.media_url = string.Format("https://xxxx.ngrok.io/Audios/09b69907-b863-4587-be19-fe98301179b8.mp3");
            //requestBody.media_url = string.Format("https://drive.google.com/file/d/xxx/view?usp=sharing");
            requestBody.media_url = string.Format("https://drive.google.com/file/d/xxx/view?usp=sharing");
            requestBody.skip_diarization = "false";
            requestBody.skip_punctuation = "false";
            requestBody.remove_disfluencies = "false";
            requestBody.filter_profanity = "false";
            requestBody.speaker_channels_count = null;
            requestBody.delete_after_seconds = "2592000";
            requestBody.custom_vocabularies = "";
            requestBody.metadata = "sample metadata";

            var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = GetAuthenticationHeader();
            var response = await client.PostAsync(urlPath, stringContent);
            var temp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseBody>(temp);
        }
```

Comment: You should deploy web server which will serve your files on host, and setup ngrok to listen web server port.

Comment: So in a test environment it won't work? If I try to use a storage provider like Google drive shouldn't it simulate having web server?

Comment: I am going to set up a FTP server on my test environment. Will keep you noted.

Comment: Ok it seems to work. Now I am looking at some security considerations. Is there a way to only allow certain domains to use the FTP server anonymously.

Comment: At production you can setup proxy like nginx, etc.